# SQL query based on order of events

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks something like this (name, action, time)

```
c1 sell 10
c1 buy  5
c1 sell 4
c1 buy  3 
c1 buy  2
c2 sell 1
c2 buy  2 
c3 buy  3
c3 sell 20
c3 sell 15
c3 buy  10
c3 buy  1
```

I would like to write an sql that outputs the clients **whose latest action was a sell** so in this case my query should return `c1, c3`.

I'm pretty new to sql so I don't know how I would structure such a query.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So, there is no "latest" action, unless a column specifies the ordering.  Let me assume that the `time` column has this information.

Then:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.time = (select max(t2.time)
                from t t2
                where t2.name = t.name
               ) and
      t.action = 'sell';
```

You can also approach this with aggregation, if you just want the clients:

```
select name
from t
group by name
having max(time) = max(case when action = 'sell' then time end);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery with grouping connected to the main by an `in` operator :

```
select *
  from t
 where action = 'sell'
   and (name, time) in
       (
        select name, max(time)
          from t
         group by name );
```